# Cartesian Product

Tags: notation, terminology

Given sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n$ how do I describe its Cartesian product $$C = A_1 \times A_2 \times \ldots \times A_n$$

in a succinct fashion? An example would be $C = \times_{i=1}^n A_i$ or $C = \times_i A_i$ (but I don't think these are used).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Abbreviated_form) mentions $\times X_i$ ; is this commonly used?

Comment: Common is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Looks good and easy to understand ; please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$$ or various abbreviations for this (if context allows):
$$ \prod_i A_i$$
$$ \prod^n A_i$$
$$ \prod A_i $$